# apply css class on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below html code,

```
<body class="page-header-fixed page-sidebar-closed-hide-logo page-content-white page-sidebar-closed" style="background-color: #F5F5F5">
```

So when page load sidebar closed CSS will get applied,

Now i am using Jquery and html storage to save and get toggle value of navigation bar,

```
      var sidebar = $('.page-sidebar');
      var sidebarMenu = $('.page-sidebar-menu');
      var body = $('body');

      if (localStorage.getItem("toggler") == 'close')
      {
        body.addClass("page-sidebar-closed");
        sidebarMenu.addClass("page-sidebar-menu-closed");
      }
      else
      {
        body.removeClass("page-sidebar-closed");
        sidebarMenu.removeClass("page-sidebar-menu-closed");
      }
```

My problem is when page load it always load with closed side bar, this is not a problem when user had clicked as "Closed" and that is stored as localstorage, page loads correctly with sidebar closed,

But when user had clicked as "Open", page first load with closed sidebar because it has given class 'page-sidebar-closed', and then Jquery function will open it, this gives flicker of sidebar whenever page load, like closed and open,

Can i apply some function directly on class?

Comment: Can you please provide your link so I get some more idea. Thanks.

Comment: @NarendraSolanki, it's on private domain, can not share link,

Comment: You can't do it. You need to use a server side language for this.
But maybe if you do the check in vanilla js you can put the script inline directly after open body tag. So the script run immediately.
Its happen because the jquery code run only when the document ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$( document ).ready(function() { }` to perform actions once document is ready. Here you can change class of your sidebar as per users last action. Make sure that your js files are loaded before css files (though this will increase load time) to avoid flickering.

Hope this helps, below example demonstrates the same. Color of div is changed on page ready.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // change div color to blue on page ready
    $("#demo").removeClass('red-box').addClass('blue-box');
});
```

```css
.red-box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F44336;
}

.blue-box{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="red-box"></div> <!-- div with red color -->
```